# SharePoint 2010 and JQuery accordion menu

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm following this article, downloaded both the js files and included in the master page's head section but nothing is happening.. Even no error. Any idea ?

http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2009/01/16/Creating-an-accordion-style-SharePoint-Quick-Launch-menu-with-jQuery.aspx

I'm using V4.master without much customization.

Answer (score 0):

The article you posted is referencing code from SharePoint 2007, which uses a Table layout structure in the left navigation. SharePoint 2010 V4 master page by default uses the new layout structure consisting of UL LI tags. The Jquery you added works fine its just not finding the correct CSS classes.

To fix this you should go to

1. site actions > site settings
2. master page and page layouts
3. Edit your master page properties (i suggest making a copy of the V4.master page to edit)
4. In the master page properties there is a "UI Version" you can set this to 3 and it will use the old style layout with the tables, which should allow you to use the Jquery code.

Edit : If you didnt want to revert your master page to version 3, I found this link that supports SharePoint 2010 Left Navigation accordion code. I have not tested it. http://www.sharepoint2010guru.com/sharepoint2010architecture/knoxblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15